# Sorting algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting

This is my ugly code which needs to sort my data. I'm not really familiar with C# since actually I'm a Java programmer.

How could this code be rewritten without loosing performance? I know I could use reflection, but it is bad for performance.

`sortings` is a list of the fields that have to be sorted and if it has to be ASC and DESC. `leistungen` is the data to be sorted.

The classes:

```
public class Aufzeichnung
{
    public string Mitarbeiter { get; set; }
    public int Dauer { get; set; }
    public double Kosten { get; set; }
}

public class Leistung
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Art { get; set; }
    public string Angebot { get; set; }
    public string Jahr { get; set; }
    public string Berater { get; set; }
    public string Assistent { get; set; }
    public double Preis { get; set; }
    public List<Aufzeichnung> Aufzeichnungen { get; set; }
}

public class LaufendeLeistung
{
    public string Kunde { get; set; }
    public List<Leistung> Leistungen { get; set; }
}
```

The algorithm:

```
internal static IEnumerable<A> Sort(List<A> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sortings.Count(); i++)
        {
            var sort = sortings.ElementAt(i).Ascending ? 1 : -1;

            if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Kunde"))
            {
                leistungen.Sort((a,b) => string.Compare(a.Kunde,b.Kunde)*sort);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < leistungen.Count(); j++)
                {
                    if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Leistung"))
                    {
                        leistungen[j].Leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Art, b.Art) * sort);
                    }
                    else if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Angebot"))
                    {
                        leistungen[j].Leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Angebot, b.Angebot) * sort);
                    }
                    else if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Jahr"))
                    {
                        leistungen[j].Leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Jahr, b.Jahr) * sort);
                    }
                    else if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Berater"))
                    {
                        leistungen[j].Leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Berater, b.Berater) * sort);
                    }
                    else if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Assistent"))
                    {
                        leistungen[j].Leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Assistent, b.Assistent) * sort);
                    }
                    else if (sortings.ElementAt(i).Field.Equals("Mitarbeiter"))
                    {
                        for (var k = 0; k < leistungen[j].Leistungen.Count(); k++)
                        {
                            if (leistungen[j].Leistungen[k].Aufzeichnungen != null)
                            {
                                leistungen[j].Leistungen[k].Aufzeichnungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Mitarbeiter, b.Mitarbeiter) * sort);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return leistungen;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition for `Sorting`? (You can insert it in blockquote with a note to not review it, if you like.)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**

My original answer does not address ascending / descending sorting dynamically. So here is my idea. Note that this is different from [@ratchetFreak answer.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104422/10221) The key is that an `IComparer<T>` automatically overrides an object's `IComparable<T>` implementation.

1. New class, `LeistungComparer : Comparer<T>`

   1. `public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer<T>` - so inherit and we get the interface.
   2. We'll pass a constructor parameter to tell which way to sort.
2. Move `Leistung.CompareTo()` code to this new class.
3. `Leistung.CompareTo()` will just call the `LeistungComparer.Compare()` - that's all!

**The above in action:**

```
// ***** default ascending sort
Leistung yourLeistung = new Leistung( );
Leistung yourLeistung2 = new Leistung( );
List<Leistung> yourList = new List<Leistung>();
yourList.Add(yourLeistung);
yourList.Add(yourLeistung2);
// stuff happens, then...
yourList.Sort();

// override
yourList.Sort( new LeistungComparer( SortOrder.descend ) );
```

**Details**

```
public enum SortOrder { undefined, ascend, descend }

public class LeistungComparer : Comparer<Leistung>
{
    protected int SortBy { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default sort order is ascending
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sortOrder">defaults to ascend</param>
    public LeistungComparer( SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.ascend )
    {
        if ( sortOrder == SortOrder.ascend ) SortBy = 1;
        if ( sortOrder == SortOrder.descend ) SortBy = -1;
        if ( sortOrder == SortOrder.undefined )
            throw new NotImplementedException( "Sort Order is undefined" );
    }


    public override int Compare( Leistung x, Leistung y )
    {
        int result = SortBy;

        if ( x != null && y == null ) return result;
        if ( x == null && y != null ) return result * SortBy;
        if ( x == null && y == null ) return 0;

        result = x.Art.CompareTo( y.Art ) * SortBy;

        if ( result == 0 )
            result = CompareAngebot( x, y );

        return result * SortBy;
    }

    protected int CompareAngebot( Leistung x, Leistung y )
    {
        int result = SortBy;
        result = x.Angebot.CompareTo( y.Angebot ) * SortBy;

        if ( result == 0 )
            result = CompareJahr( x, y );

        return result;
    }

    protected int CompareJahr( Leistung x, Leistung y )
    {
        // you get the idea

        return 1;
    }
}


public class Leistung : IComparable<Leistung>
{
    // properties removed for readability

    protected LeistungComparer Comparer { get; set; }

    public Leistung (LeistungComparer comparer = null){
        Comparer = comparer ?? new LeistungComparer();
    }

    public int CompareTo( Leistung other )
    {
        return Comparer.Compare( this, other );
    }
}
```

**End Edit**

### NOTE: Original answer follows. It has not been modified.

---

---

The idomatic way to enable sorting is to implement the `IComparable` interface. And this will definitely simplify the sorting code. So:

```
public class Leistungen : IComparable<Leistungen> {  }
public class Aufzeichnung : IComparable<Aufzeichnung> { }
```

then you can sort like this:

```
List<Leistungen> myLeistungen;  // pretend we instantiated it too.

myLeistungen.Sort();
```

---

And if you want different sort algorithms then create an `IComparer` class for each one as suggested by @ratchetfreak. then you can do the following - which will override your `IComparalble` implementation in the class `Leistungen`:

```
myLeistungen.Sort(myDifferentComparer);
```

---

**IComparable Implementation**

This demonstrates how to compare multiple properties. Both of your classes will implement using this pattern. When `Leistungen.CompareTo()` gets down to comparing its `List<Aufzeichnung>`, well `Aufzeichnung.CompareTo()` takes care of that!

```
public class Leistungen : IComparable<Leistungen> {
    \\ implementing the generic version means we don't 
    \\ check for or cast to the correct type.
    public int CompareTo(Leistungen other) {
        int result = 1; // "this" is > "other"

        if(other == null) return result;

        result = this.Art.CompareTo(other.Art);

        if(result == 0)
            result = CompareAngebot(other);

        return result;
    }

    protected int CompareAngebot(Leistungen other) {
        int result = 1;
        result = this.Angebot.CompareTo(other.Angebot);

        if(result == 0)
           result = CompareJahr(other);

        return result;
    }

    protected int CompareJahr(Leistungen other) { // you get the idea }

    // ....

    protected int CompareAufzeichnungList(Leistungen other) {
        // last property in our compare chain, so it's real simple

        return this.Aufzeichnungen.CompareTo(other.Aufzeichnungen);
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand the code in the question correctly, then it actually provides a way to order by one property first and another property afterwards (with a choice of asc/desc for each property).

Comment: "with a choice of asc/desc for each property" - No. This is why I mention implementing `IComparer` for other sort algorithms.

Comment: Yes `with a choice of asc/desc for each property` is also needed, my code does it.

Comment: @radarbob It does not do it explicitly - it's more of a side effect of actually re-ordering the list several times.

Comment: @hangy - _with a choice of asc/desc for each property_ ...  Oh, duh.  Yes you are right. each property-compareTo-method could evaluate for asc or desc as desired. In my comment that I deleted, by "choice" I was thinking a method parameter for that. Of course `CompareTo` does not provide a parameter for specifying asc or desc.

Answer (score 5):

One of the improvements you can make is a `foreach` on `sortings` instead of using `.ElementAt(i)` (which will always be slower).

Another improvement would be to convert all those `if` statements in the `else` block to a `switch`.

Third, you should be using `nameof(...)` instead of string constants. This way, if something gets refactored, the name change persists without needing to go through all the strings and look for names to change. (For example, `nameof(Leistung.Angebot)` will return `Angebot`.) Do note: this is C#6.0 only.

Another suggestion is to create a `Comparison<Leistung>` variable to hold your delegate for comparison in. That way, you can create it once and run through each sort as needed. This does require you to create an extra `else if` and duplicate your `for (var j = 0; j ...` loop, but it makes it a bit more maintainable (and likely faster) in the end.

Fifth, I would recommend replacing `for (var j = 0; ...` and `for (var k = 0; ...` with `foreach` loops. They *should* be faster (if I recall correctly), and you don't have a need to keep track of `j` or `k` in them.

Another C#6.0 feature you can take advantage of is the `?.` null-condition check to remove the null-check in `Mitarbeiter` sort. `Aufzeichnungen?.Sort` will only call `.Sort` if `Aufzeichnungen` is not null.

Lastly, there's no need for `string.Equals`. In C# you can directly compare strings with `==`.

---

All in all, here is the new version (with all the edits I recommend).

Yes, it's longer, but it's also more robust, duplicates less, and should likely perform better.

```
internal static IEnumerable<A> Sort(List<A> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings)
{
    foreach (var sorting in sortings)
    {
        var sort = sorting.Ascending ? 1 : -1;

        if (sorting.Field == nameof(LaufendeLeistung.Kunde))
        {
            leistungen.Sort((a, b) => string.Compare(a.Kunde, b.Kunde) * sort);
        }
        else if (sorting.Field == nameof(Aufzeichnung.Mitarbeiter))
        {
            Comparison<Aufzeichnung> comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Mitarbeiter, b.Mitarbeiter) * sort;

            foreach (var element in leistungen)
            {
                foreach (var subElement in element.Leistungen)
                {
                    subElement.Aufzeichnungen?.Sort(comparison);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Comparison<Leistung> comparison;

            switch (sorting.Field)
            {
                case nameof(Leistung):
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Art, b.Art) * sort;
                    break;
                case nameof(Leistung.Angebot):
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Angebot, b.Angebot) * sort;
                    break;
                case nameof(Leistung.Jahr):
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Jahr, b.Jahr) * sort;
                    break;
                case nameof(Leistung.Berater):
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Berater, b.Berater) * sort;
                    break;
                case nameof(Leistung.Assistent):
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Assistent, b.Assistent) * sort;
                    break;
                default: // This will perform the same sort as sorting by `Leistung`. The nice thing about this is if the value in `sorting.Field` is an invalid field, it will still sort by *something*.
                    comparison = (a, b) => string.Compare(a.Art, b.Art) * sort;
                    break;
            }

            foreach (var element in leistungen)
            {
                element.Leistungen.Sort(comparison);
            }
        }
    }

    return leistungen;
}
```

Comment: The Switch statement does not work, compiler says `The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: `nameof` is a C# 6.0 feature.

Comment: @Emaborsa The `nameof` feature requires C#6.0 to work (as is indicated by the last sentence in that paragraph), if you don't have C#6.0, you will have to stick to the string literals.

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is some potential for optimization even without rewriting the code completely.

1. By using `sortings.ElementAt(i)` over and over again, you are actually getting the enumerable element every time. As of now, I see no reason not to use `foreach (var sorting in sortings)` and using the `sorting` variable inside the loop, instead of the `for` loop.
2. Depending on how many and which sort fields get passed to the `Sort` method via the `sortings` parameter, you may be re-sorting the same list(s) over and over again. Since List.Sort actually re-sorts the array every time, this not negligible.
3. There is exactly one case where you need to sort the `leistungen` list itself and one where the `Aufzeichnungen` list needs to be sorted. You can identify them before iterating through everything (just use the last entry of the `sortings` list that matches the field name to get the correct sort order) and apply them seperately from the loop.

From an outside perspective, it could also be unexpected that the `leistungen` list is sorted in place and then returned as an `IEnumerable<A>`. I would at least add some documentation that states that the input list will be modified.

A huge downside of your could could be that you depend on `Array.Sort` being called in order to implement the sort with several levels. My suggestion would be to try using the built in LINQ methods instead. By chaining `OrderBy`/`ThenBy` calls, you could avoid running the sort algorithm a lot of times, and instead use the lazy execution of LINQ. Here's a suggestion on how it could work:

```
public static class Sorter<A> where A : LaufendeLeistung
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Func<Leistung, string>> leistungKeySelectors;

    static Sorter()
    {
        var selectors = new Dictionary<string, Func<Leistung, string>>();

        selectors.Add("Leistung", l => l.Art);
        selectors.Add("Angebot", l => l.Angebot);
        selectors.Add("Jahr", l => l.Jahr);
        selectors.Add("Berater", l => l.Berater);
        selectors.Add("Assistent", l => l.Assistent);

        leistungKeySelectors = selectors;
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<A> Sort(List<A> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings)
    {
        if (leistungen == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(leistungen));
        }

        return sortings == null ? leistungen : SortImpl(leistungen, sortings);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<A> SortImpl(IEnumerable<A> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings)
    {
        var customerSorting = sortings.LastOrDefault(s => "Kunde".Equals(s.Field, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        var employeeSorting = sortings.LastOrDefault(s => "Mitarbeiter".Equals(s.Field, StringComparison.Ordinal));

        if (customerSorting != null)
        {
            leistungen = leistungen.OrderBy(k => k.Kunde, customerSorting);
        }

        var leistungenSortings = sortings.Where(s => !"Kunde".Equals(s.Field, StringComparison.Ordinal) && !"Mitarbeiter".Equals(s.Field, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToList();

        foreach (var laufendeLeistung in leistungen)
        {
            if (laufendeLeistung.Leistungen != null)
            {
                laufendeLeistung.Leistungen = ProcessLeistungen(laufendeLeistung.Leistungen, leistungenSortings, employeeSorting).ToList();
            }

            yield return laufendeLeistung;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Leistung> ProcessLeistungen(IEnumerable<Leistung> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings, Sorting employeeSorting)
    {
        foreach (var leistung in SortLeistungenByProperties(leistungen, sortings))
        {
            if (employeeSorting != null && leistung.Aufzeichnungen != null)
            {
                leistung.Aufzeichnungen = leistung.Aufzeichnungen.OrderBy(a => a.Mitarbeiter, employeeSorting).ToList();
            }

            yield return leistung;
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Leistung> SortLeistungenByProperties(IEnumerable<Leistung> leistungen, IEnumerable<Sorting> sortings)
    {
        foreach (var sorting in sortings)
        {
            // Just an alternative to the switch/case statement.
            Func<Leistung, string> selector;
            if (leistungKeySelectors.TryGetValue(sorting.Field, out selector))
            {
                leistungen = leistungen.OrderBy(selector, sorting);
            }
        }

        return leistungen;
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector, Sorting sorting)
    {
        var result = source as IOrderedEnumerable<T>;
        if (result != null)
        {

            result = sorting.Ascending ? result.ThenBy(keySelector) : result.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        }
        else
        {
            result = sorting.Ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes that there is actually no need to sort the `List<LaufendeLeistung>` in place, nor should any consumers depend on `Leistungen` or `Aufzeichnungen` not being replaced (there is a public setter after all). There might be slightly higher memory usage etc., because of some allocations (Enumerators, Dictionary, Lists), but it could still be faster with several `sortings`, because of not actually re-sorting the array that backs the List several times. (If this matters, benchmark it. :))

Comment: 1. You're right, I can export the variable in order taht the code is more readable.   
2+3.I know, but i asked a way to simplify the code, not just to improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

you could define a `IComparer` that holds several `IComparers` and returns the first result that isn't 0:

```
class CascadedComparer<T> : IComparer<T>{

    IList<IComparer<T>> comparings; //fill in constructor

    public int Compare(T x, T y){
        foreach(var comp in comparings){
            int r = comp.compare(x, y);

            if(r!=0) 
                return r;
        }
        return 0; //all returned 0
    }

}
```

Then you can pass an instance of that filled with the field specific comparers to the `sort` method of `leistungen[j].Leistungen`.

The `Sorting` doesn't need to hold the string value of the field to compare but instead a Comparer (or a mapping function).

Ortherwise you can build a `map<string, IComparer<A>>` and then you can get the comparer directly from the map.

Comment: To be honest, i didn't exactly understand how to implement this in my code...